# Interchanging limits and logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

This is probably not too smart, just wondering of the name of this rule:
$$
\log \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0}\log f(x)
$$
A reference to a source and/or proof would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the function inside the limit symbol is continuous at $x_0$, the statement follows from the continuity of that function. Search for "interchanging limits," and you're sure to find sources.

Edit: [Here's](http://www.scribd.com/doc/87423541/2/Section-8-2-Interchange-of-Limits) something worthwhile from an introductory real analysis textbook.

Answer (score 0):

It's called continuity.  It's the same as saying that the logarithm function is continuous.