# When does $\log(\lim_{x\to c} f(x)) = \lim_{x\to c} \log(f(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, logarithms

When does $$\log(\lim_{x\to c} f(x)) = \lim_{x\to c} \log(f(x))$$

I have seen different things from different sources. For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/211388) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500867/why-is-lim-x-to-cgfx-g-lim-x-to-cfx). Does $f(x)$ have to be continuous at c, does $\log (f(x))$ have to be continuous at c, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)> 0,$ then it is OK, i.e, Logrithmic function need to be continuous at $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x).$

Comment: That's all one needs here.  +1