# limit of $I=\int_{2}^{a}\frac{x}{x^3-1}dx$ as a approaches $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I need to find the limit of $I=\int_{2}^{a}\frac{x}{x^3-1}dx$ as a approaches $\infty$

I got $I=\int \frac{x}{x^3-1}dx=(\frac{1}{3}\ln(x-1)-\frac{1}{6}\ln(x^2+x+1)-\frac{6}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}) + C$

$I=\frac{1}{3}\ln(a-1)-\frac{1}{6}\ln(a^2+a+1)+\frac{1}{6}\ln7-2\sqrt{3}(\arctan\frac{2a+1}{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}})$

Now I get stuck when I try to find the limit.I know the limit of arctan($\infty$)=$\pi/2$ but what about those ln?

The final answer should be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\pi+\frac{1}{6}\ln7$

Comment: Yes, I know those rules

Answer (score 1):

Note that we got

$$a^2+a+1=\frac{a^3-1}{a-1}$$

Thus

\begin{align*}
\frac13\log(a-1)-\frac16\log(a^2+a+1)&=\frac16\left(2\log(a-1)-\log\left(\frac{a^3-1}{a-1}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac16\log\left(\frac{(a-1)^3}{a^3-1}\right)\\
&=\frac16\log\left(\frac{a^3-3a^3+3a-1}{a^3-1}\right)
\end{align*}

As the logarithm is a continuous function we may [interchange it with the limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211387/interchanging-limits-and-logarithms). The inner expression clearly tends to $1$ as $a\to\infty$ we conclude that

> $$\therefore~\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac13\log(a-1)-\frac16\log(a^2+a+1)~=~\log(1)~=~0$$

The correct result for the integral follows.

Comment: I don't think I understand.I get what what you say but how to find the limit?The limit should be infinity..

Comment: @DaniVaja See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{3}\ln(a-1)-\frac{1}{6}\ln(a^2+a+1)=\frac{1}{6}\ln((a-1)^2)-\frac{1}{6}\ln(a^2+a+1)=\frac{1}{6}\log \left(\frac{a^2-2 a+1}{a^2+a+1}\right)\to 0$$