# An expression for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2^n}\left(1 + x^{1/n}\right)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, average

> I am looking for a closed form answer to the limit ($x<1$): $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2^n}\left(1 + x^{1/n}\right)^n$$

---

For context, I was studying weighted averages and considered $$\left(\frac12(x^{1/n} + y^{1/n})\right)^{n}$$ to be a good way to weight averages in favour of the lower number (similar to root mean squared, but kinda reversed). I think was studying what happens for different values of $n$. For $x=3$, $y=5$, I found that this limit seems to converge to $3.78962712197\dots$ but I do not recognise where this number comes from. Rearranging the above average formula gives $$\frac{y}{2^n}\left(1+\left(\frac xy\right)^{1/n}\right)^n$$and this is what inspired the question. I see it looks similar to some kind of exponential, but it isn't quite there. I also tried exponentiating and logging the whole expression to bring down the $n$, but I didn't know how to deal with the power inside the brackets then. My main issue is that since $1/n$ goes to $0$, the thing thats raised to this power goes to $1$ (and so is not small) so series expansions can't be used.

Thanks!

Comment: For all $x>0$, doesn't $\sqrt[n]{x}$ go to $1$ as $n\to\infty$?  So then you have a number clearly larger than $1$, we'll make it more explicit, a number eventually larger than $1.5$ being raised to an ever increasing power?  Why are you thinking this doesn't diverge to infinity?

Comment: In fact, that's why "series expansions can't be used" -- because it diverges.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, I do know it diverges to infinity, but I wanted to know exactly how. If you read the explanation afterwards, I realised that the entire expression seems to converge. So i think that the limit I am after will have some term which cancels out with the $2^n$ term so that it cancels out overall. Does this make sense?

Comment: I edited the question to include the $1/2^n$ term to clear that up

Comment: Incidentally, both of the answers below indicate that the numerical value that you computed for the case x = 3 and y = 5 seems incorrect. $5 \times \sqrt{3/5} = \sqrt{15} \approx 3.873$.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, perhaps it could have been some floating point issue with my script. I had: $$n=10000000000 , z = 3.8729773790987037\\
n=100000000000 , z=3.8729945789310647\\
n=1000000000000 , z=3.872994578963018\\
n=10000000000000 , z =3.874714916031831\\
n=100000000000000 , z=3.7896271219715993\\
n=1000000000000000 , z=3.7896271219716295\\
n=10000000000000000 , z=1.0\\
n=100000000000000000 , z=1.0$$So the earlier numbers seem very close to the actual value. Something definitely broke down at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have for $x>0$ that
$$
\frac{1}{{2^n }}\left( {1 + x^{1/n} } \right)^n  = \left( {1 + \frac{{x^{1/n}  - 1}}{2}} \right)^n  = \left( {1 + \frac{{1 + \frac{1}{n}\log x + O\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 x}}{{n^2 }}} \right) - 1}}{2}} \right)^n  = \left( {1 + \frac{{\log \sqrt x }}{n} + O\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 x}}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)^n  \to e^{\log \sqrt x }  = \sqrt x .
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where does the following come from? As $n\to\infty,$$$x^{1/n}\sim1+\frac1n\log x + O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Taylor expansion of the function $e^y$, and using $x^{1/n} = e^{\ln(x) / n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$a_n=2^{-n} \left(1+x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n\implies \log(a_n)=-n\log(2)+n\log \left(1+x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$
Now, use Taylor expansion for large $n$ to get
$$\log(a_n)=\frac{\log (x)}{2}+\frac{\log ^2(x)}{8 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

So, the limit is $\sqrt x$.

**Edit**

For your curiosity,
$$\log(a_n)=\frac 12\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{E_k(1) \log ^{k+1}(x)}{  (k+1)! \,n^k}$$
where appear Euler polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What are you Taylor expanding there? How do you get these powers of logs?

Comment: @william $$1+x^{\frac 1n}=1+e^{\frac{\log(x)} n}$$

Comment: Ahh ok I see it now thanks. By the way, shouldn't the last term be $O(1/n^2)$? I think the term (after multiplying by the $n$) would be something like $$\frac{5\log^3x}{24n^2}$$

Comment: @william. If you want more terms $$\log(a_n)=\frac{\log (x)}{2}+\frac{\log ^2(x)}{8 n}-\frac{\log ^4(x)}{192
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ making $$a_n=\sqrt x \left(1+\frac{\log ^2(x)}{8 n}+\frac{\log ^4(x)}{128
   n^2} \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hand-wavy argument but I thought it was fun so I'll share it. Let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{\left(1+x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n}}{2^{n}}$, and assume $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ exists, and that the limit of derivatives, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x)$, exists and is equal to $f'(x)$. Then,
$$\begin{align}f_n'(x)&=\underbrace{\frac{(1+x^{\frac{1}{n}})^n}{2^n}}_{f_n(x)}\cdot\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x\left(1+x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)}
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{x\left(1+x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)}
\\
f'(x)&=\frac{f(x)}{2x}
\\
\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\ \mathrm{d}x&=\int\frac{1}{2x}\ \mathrm{d}x
\\
\ln |f(x)|&=\frac{1}{2}\ln |x|+C
\\
f(x)&=\pm C_2\sqrt{\left|x\right|}
\end{align}$$

Then, given $f(1)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(1)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1$ and that $f,x\ge 0$, we see $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the logarithm is continuous, ([Interchanging limits and logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211387/interchanging-limits-and-logarithms)), with $f=\frac{1}{2^n}(1+x^{1/n})^n$

$$\log \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log f$$

$$\log f = \frac{\log (1+x^{1/n}) - \log 2}{\frac{1}{n}} $$

Applying L'Hopital's rule:

$$\log f \rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^{1/n-1}}{1+x^{1/n}}\log x=\frac{1}{2} \log x $$

Thus

$$f \rightarrow x^{1/2}$$